# Blazor binding to text input does not work after entering a value into the input

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My requirement is to have a text input where users can enter text but for which the value can also be set otherwise (e.g., via a button).
I use .Net 7 in a blazor server project.
I created the following simple UI to reproduce an issue I have in a more complex construct:
[image: Simple UI]

Razor Code:

```
Text Input:
<input type="text" @bind-Value=Value @bind-Value:event="oninput" />
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCounter">Increment Counter and set Value </button>
<br />
Current Value: @Value
<br />
Current Counter Value: @_counter
```

C# Code:

```
@code {
    private int _counter = 1000;

    private string? Value { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCounter()
    {
        _counter++;
        Value = _counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I click the button, the value in the text input is set as expected. I.e., it is set to the current value of the counter and the counter is incremented.
When I enter something into the text input, the value is shown below the button ("Current Value").
However, now the button does not update the content of the text input anymore.
The plain text for `@Value` still shows that the `Value` property is set as expected.
The binding from the text input to the `Value` property still works but not the other way round.
Any ideas how to solve this are very welcome.

I tried:

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `Value` property.
- Call `StateHasChanged` within the `IncrementCounter()`.
- Call `StateHasChanged` within the `Value` property.
- Call `StateHasChanged` via another button.
- Another example where the text input was in a component with `Value` as a `Parameter`. In this example I also implemented an `ValueChanged EventCallback`.

Nothing worked.

Sorry, I was desparate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@bind-value` (lower case 'v') or `@bind` on it's own.

```
<input type="text" @bind-value=Value @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<input type="text" @bind=Value @bind:event="oninput" />
```

[Blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/7bxhl6hr)

Answer (score 0):

As an add on to @RBee's answer, you can do away with the text conversion code and bind directly to the counter.

The Razor compiler will implement the necessary conversion code behind the scenes when it builds the bind functionality into the generated C# component class.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="p-2 mb-3">
    <label class="label">
        Counter Input:
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="number" @bind="_counter" @bind:event="oninput" />
</div>
<div class="mb-3 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCounter">Increment Counter and set Value </button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Current Counter Value: @_counter</pre>
</div>

@code {
    @code {
        private int _counter = 1000;

        private void IncrementCounter()
        {
            _counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The purpose of the counter was just to demonstrate setting the `Value` in code. It could also have been a constant. I only used it in more complex scenarios to track which component contains which value.